# Adding links to full change forms for inline items in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms, hyperlink

I have a standard admin change form for an object, with the usual StackedInline forms for a ForeignKey relationship. I would like to be able to link each inline item to its corresponding  full-sized change form, as the inline item has inlined items of its own, and I can't nest them.

I've tried everything from custom widgets to custom templates, and can't make anything work. So far, the "solutions" I've seen in the form of snippets just plain don't seem to work for inlines. I'm getting ready to try some DOM hacking with jQuery just to get it working and move on.

I hope I must be missing something very simple, as this seems like such a simple task!

Using Django 1.2.

Comment: I found the answer given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120813 better.

Comment: Django >= 1.8, use `show_change_link` http://stackoverflow.com/a/28170958/3218806

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had similar problem and I came up with custom widget plus some tweaks to model form. Here is the widget:

```
from django.utils.safestring import  mark_safe    

class ModelLinkWidget(forms.Widget):
    def __init__(self, obj, attrs=None):
        self.object = obj
        super(ModelLinkWidget, self).__init__(attrs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if self.object.pk:
            return mark_safe(
                u'<a target="_blank" href="../../../%s/%s/%s/">%s</a>' %\
                      (
                       self.object._meta.app_label,
                       self.object._meta.object_name.lower(),
                       self.object.pk, self.object
                       )
            )
        else:
            return mark_safe(u'')
```

Now since widget for each inline need to get different object in constructor you can't just set it in standard way, but in Form's **init** method:

```
class TheForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    # required=False is essential cause we don't
    # render input tag so there will be no value submitted.
    link = forms.CharField(label='link', required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TheForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # instance is always available, it just does or doesn't have pk.
        self.fields['link'].widget = ModelLinkWidget(self.instance)
```

Comment: I haven't had time to try this, but it *looks* like it should work. :) Thanks.

Comment: This is a fine solution, it can be made even more fine by combining it with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197280/for-a-django-model-how-can-i-get-the-django-admin-url-to-add-another-or-list-o

Comment: Also, this may be vulnerable to XSS attacks (depending on the objects presented and where they come from), and you really don't want those in the admin -- render the string with a Django Template instead of python's %.

Answer (score 139):

There is a property called [`show_change_link`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.show_change_link) since Django 1.8.

Comment: A quick note that you must register the model in the admin site (not just the inline), or the change link simply doesn't display above the inline (Django 3.2).

Answer (score 52):

I did something like the following in my admin.py:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class MyModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyModel

    def admin_link(self, instance):
        url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (instance._meta.app_label,  
                                              instance._meta.module_name),
                      args=(instance.id,))
        return format_html(u'<a href="{}">Edit</a>', url)
        # … or if you want to include other fields:
        return format_html(u'<a href="{}">Edit: {}</a>', url, instance.title)

    readonly_fields = ('admin_link',)
```

Comment: I've added this to my admin but I do not see the link. The column has been added tho.  Any ideas?

Comment: Nice solution. Very clean

Comment: when you save the edit form, it should return to the original parent edit page not to the change list of the edited object.

Comment: It seems that in Django 1.8 instead of `instance._meta.module_name` it should read `instance._meta.model_name`

Comment: True module_name should be model_name

Comment: This solution works, but as noted from some of the other comments, use `instance.pk` instead of `instance.id`, `instance._meta.model_name` instead of `instance._meta.module_name`, and add `admin_link` to fields, e.g `fields = (..., 'admin_link', ...)`

Answer (score 33):

**The currently accepted solution here is good work, but it's out of date.**

Since Django 1.3, there is a built-in property called `show_change_link = True` that addresses this issue.

This can be added to any StackedInline or TabularInline object. For example:

```
class ContactListInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ContactList
    fields = ('name', 'description', 'total_contacts',)
    readonly_fields = ('name', 'description', 'total_contacts',)
    show_change_link = True
```

The result will be something line this:

[image: tabular inline using show_change_link]

Comment: But what if I want a title to be a hyperlink, but not a label next to the title?

Answer (score 3):

Quentin's answer above works, but you also need to specify fields = ('admin_link',)

Answer (score 2):

There is a module for this purpose. Check out:
[django-relatives](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-relatives)

Answer (score 0):

I think: args=[instance.id] should be args=[instance.pk]. It worked for me!