# How do I link to a model's listing in the Django admin interface?

Tags: django, django-admin

Linking to a model *instance* is fairly easy in Django: `reverse('admin:myapp_mymodel_change, args=(myinstance.pk,))`, but how do I link to the list (*not the changelist*) of objects that are of the MyApp.MyModel type?

My dirty hack works, but is a bit nasty:

```
admin_model_list = reverse('admin:myapp_mymodel_add')[:-5]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [For a django model, how can I get the django admin URL to add another, or list objects, etc.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197280/for-a-django-model-how-can-i-get-the-django-admin-url-to-add-another-or-list-o)

Answer (score 1):

That *is* the changelist.

```
reverse('admin:myapp_mymodel_changelist') == reverse('admin:myapp_mymodel_add')[:-4]
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't see anything in the docs about the ID being optional for the `admin:{}_{}_changelist` lookup and thought it was just history logs for each instance.  Dupe question now that your other post was fixed ;)

Comment: Hah, sorry for the confusion, could have been that post from 3 years ago!