# Django Admin: How to edit the object on the other end of an inline ManyToMany link on the same change form?

Tags: django, django-admin

When using Django Admin, I can show ManyToMany links in form of a < select > widget by specifying an inline.  But as far as I can tell, there is no way to either edit the object on the other side of the link from the same form, or show a URL to take me to the linked object.   Either would be fine with me, but I would prefer the former.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a link from the Django admin page of one object to the admin page of a related object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919780/how-do-i-add-a-link-from-the-django-admin-page-of-one-object-to-the-admin-page-o)

Comment: Thanks! That did help me get a link displayed to point to the change form for the other object.  I would still love to know how to edit the object inline though...

Comment: You can't right now. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681258/nested-inlines-in-the-django-admin which I linked to in my question for more info (and the links in those posts)

Comment: Too bad, at least we have a workaround I guess.  Thanks again for the tips.