# Add url to a field in TabularInline in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

The questions is not actual

---

How can I make links from field author for TabularInline? For now I implement this (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011307/9112151):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


def add_link_field(target_model = None, field = '', link_text = unicode):
    def add_link(cls):
        reverse_name = target_model or cls.model.__name__.lower()
        def link(self, instance):
            app_name = instance._meta.app_label
            reverse_path = "admin:%s_%s_change" % (app_name, reverse_name)
            link_obj = getattr(instance, field, None) or instance
            url = reverse(reverse_path, args = (link_obj.id,))
            return mark_safe("<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (url, link_text(link_obj)))
        link.allow_tags = True
        link.short_description = reverse_name + ' link'
        cls.link = link
        cls.readonly_fields = list(getattr(cls, 'readonly_fields', [])) + ['link']
        return cls
    return add_link


@add_link_field('author')
class PostInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Post
```

Maybe there is built-in decision?

Answer (score 1):

[Set `show_change_link = True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.show_change_link) on your inline to display a link to the admin change form for an inline object

```
class PostInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Post
    show_change_link = True
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to display a link to author in inline

Comment: @АльбертАлександров author should be rendered as a select/dropdown and should have a pencil and plus icon next to it? Those icons link to the add and edit forms for author/User, is this not what you want?

Comment: It should be readonly. Just a link to author change view

Comment: found out how. thanks