# Adding an hyperlink to another Model inside Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have something which sounds trivial but I cant find a way to implement in django admin.

I have a Model which I am showing in my admin. I am using a TabularInline to show another model which refer to the first one.

All I want is a link to click on my current view so I'll go into the TabularInline view *only*.

The reason I need it is simple. My second model admin registertion also contains another TabularInline to a third model. so I cant see the Inline from the first model.

The Models are pretty simple. I am implementing a Voting system over several cretirias. So I want my Item model admin to show all the users which votes and the final score. But the Vote model breaks down the cretirias that the user votes for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer discusses this in some detail:

[Django InlineModelAdmin: Show partially an inline model and link to the complete model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120813/django-inlinemodeladmin-show-partially-an-inline-model-and-link-to-the-complete)

But this is what I use:

https://gist.github.com/3013072