# Django inline link to model editing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I know this issue has been asked more than once, but as Django is evolving with new version, I'll ask the question again :

I am using the model User (Django User, not in my models.py) and create another model with a Foreign key to User.

`models.py` :

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I can simply display every `Plan` in my user by doing this in `admin.py` :

```
class PlanInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Plan
    extra = 0

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ordering = ('-date_joined', 'username')
    inlines = [PlanInline,]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

But things are about to get more tricky. I want to add a model that has a foreign key pointing to `Plan` :

```
class Order(models.Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey('Plan')
```

And I want to be able to see all `Orders` for each `Plan`. As of today, it is impossible to have nested inlines in Django Admin (without editing the HTML, which I want to avoid) :

```
User 
     -> Plan 1 
              -> Order 1
              -> Order 2

     -> Plan 2
              -> Order 3
```

So my idea is to display in the `User Admin` only **A LINK** for each plan, to the page to edit `Plans`, and put `Orders` as inline :

```
class OrderInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Order
    extra = 0

class PlanAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OrderInline,]

admin.site.register(Plan, PlanAdmin)
```

The question is, how do I display a link to a Plan in my User Admin?

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ordering = ('-date_joined', 'username')
    ??? LINK ????
```

I saw some solutions on this topic : [Django InlineModelAdmin: Show partially an inline model and link to the complete model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120813/django-inlinemodeladmin-show-partially-an-inline-model-and-link-to-the-complete), but they are a bit "dirty' as they make us write HTML and absolute path into the code.

Then I saw this ticket on Djangoproject : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13163. It seems exactly what I'm looking for, and the ticket is "fixed". So I tried adding like in the fix `show_change_link = True` :

```
class PlanInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Plan
    extra = 0
    show_change_link = True

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ordering = ('-date_joined', 'username')
    show_change_link = True
    inlines = [UserProfileInline, PlanInline]
```

But it doesn't work (and I have no log or error).

Is there any way to do this in a clean way?

Comment: I'm not sure that ticket does what you describe, but in any case it was only closed four days ago. Are you running against the HEAD of the Django repo?

Comment: "Are you running against the HEAD of the Django repo?" I'm sorry I don't get it (not a native english speaker). And yeah now that you point it out, I guess the fix is either for 1.7 or my Django is not up to date with the fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest adding a custom `PlanInline` method that returns the link and see if it helps. Something along these lines:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class PlanInline(TabularInline):
   model = Plan
   readonly_fields = ('change_link',)
   ...other options here...

   def change_link(self, obj):
      return mark_safe('<a href="%s">Full edit</a>' % \
                        reverse('admin:myapp_plan_change',
                        args=(obj.id,)))
```

Basically all we do here is create the custom method that returns a link to the change page (this specific implementation is not tested, sorry if there is any parse error but you get the idea) and then add it to the readonly_fields as described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

A couple of notes for the `change_link` method: You need to replace 'myapp' in the view name with your actual application name. The `mark_safe` method just marks the text as safe for the template engine to render it as html.

Comment: Yeah that's the solution a went for as it seems there is no other way yet (a variant of this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21079750/3768672)

Answer (score 11):

Update for django 1.8

```
show_change_link = True
```

https://github.com/django/django/pull/2957/files

Comment: this should be right answer now.