# Multi level Inlines Django

Tags: python, django

This is my models

```
from django.db import models

class Page(models.Model):
    page_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Question(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Option(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    option = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image_class = models.CharField(max_length=75)
```

this is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Page, Question, Option

class OptionInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Option
    extra = 1

class QuestionInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Question
    extra = 1
    inlines = [OptionInline]

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [QuestionInline]

admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

basically i want this multi level relation to appear as a multi level inline in the admin site. can someone please help out

Comment: Django's admin doesn't support nested inlines so you'll have to write your own `ModelAdmin` and `Inline` subclasses, as well as all the relevant template and javascript code.

Comment: No answer is accepted yet? Is the question still valid? Did you find any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using nested inlines, Django 1.8 provides the [InlineModelAdmin.show_change_link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.show_change_link)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Page, Question, Option

class OptionInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Option
    extra = 1

class QuestionInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Question
    extra = 1
    show_change_link = True


class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [QuestionInline,]

admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)


class QuestionAdmin((admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OptionInline,]

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

This way, when you save the `Page` model -having completed the inline `Question` model- a link called 'change' will appear at the saved instance of the inline `Question` model. Clicking it, you will land at the main page of the `Question` model instance with the `Option` model as inline.

When you complete the `Option` model inline and hit the 'save and continue editing', the back button should return you to the relevant `Page` instance.

There is also [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120813/django-inlinemodeladmin-show-partially-an-inline-model-and-link-to-the-complete/21079750#21079750) which describes how you can achieve the same result if you use previous Django versions.

Answer (score 1):

Django does not support it out of the box, but there is project called [django-nested-inline](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline) that will do the job. Also you can make your own solution.